# How can I loop through a list of lists from a firestore in Java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make an app that requires me to store data in a document that is in a collection in a Firestore. Inside of this document, there are a bunch of `HashMap`s that have a String as a key, and then an `ArrayList` as a value.

I would like to loop through the values of these `HashMap`s to be able to compare what is inside of them. The code I have so far lets me access these `HashMap`s and print them out to me. The only problem is that when I try to start a double `for` loop to try and access the Strings inside of these lists (that are the values of the `HashMap`s) it gives me an error saying that I cannot loop through an Object. This is the code I have for now; (credit to another stackoverflow post)

```java
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Rooms")
                 .document("ppwz").get()
                 .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                         DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                         Map<String, Object> groupHash= document.getData();

                         for (Object x: groupHash.values()) {
                             //would like to create a second for loop here to try and access the strings within the HashMap values
                         }
                     }
                 });
```

Thank you very much in advance. I am quite new to this so please be indulgent.

Comment: You need to cast those Objects to ab ArrayList or whatever type the values are. You can’t iterate over an object.

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it, and indicate the exact data you want to get. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot iterate an object so you need to cast or convert it to Map<String, Object>

to cast:

```
for (Object x: groupHash.values()) {
    for (Object value: ((Map<String, Object>)x).values()){
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Online example: https://ideone.com/BiYios